# NetworkX Graph removing edges whose removal will not add bridges to the graph

Tags: python, networkx

What is the most effective way to determine all edges in a graph that can be removed so that there will not arise new bridges in a given graph.

Currently I always copy the graph, remove an edge and check whether the bridges and number of bridges change. I repeat this for every edge and then return the list of edges. Choose one in the list and remove it.
When I want to remove several edges I repeat the whole process several times.

What would be a better/more efficient approach. (I always need the whole candidate list.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the edges that when removed give rise to all k-edge components with k=2.

1. Search for all k-edge components in G using `nx.algorithms.connectivity.edge_kcomponents.k_edge_components` (with k=2). This will yield all vertex sets resulting from cuts with a cut size of 2.
2. Induce a subgraph for each vertex set, and combine subgraphs using `nx.compose` into a graph H.
3. Determine the difference between G and H with `nx.difference(G, H)`.

Comment: `list(nx.difference(graph, nx.compose_all([graph.subgraph(sg) for sg in nx.k_edge_components(graph, k = 3)])).edges())` doesn't yield the same result it returns a different set of edges. k=2 doesn't work my graph has no bridges, I am looking for edges that can be removed without creating bridges this way. Therefore I remove an edge and afterwards check whether the graph has a bridge. If not then I add the edge to a candidate list of removable edges.